# homestead didn't wants to start normaly

Tags: laravel, vagrant, homestead

I updated Virtualbox to 6.0.2 and Vagrant into 2.2.3 in MacOSX Siera. Also remove old laravel/homestead folder and download new one v8.0.2. But when install virtualbox and vagrant on my MacOSX and run vagrant up it make new ssh keys and move it into new virtual box machine. First indicator that I saw is that he forward only 22 port into virtual machine and make it in some strange name(previous naming is like homestead-7), and last time is homestead_default_1549352737068_70025. Here is list of logs that I get from console:

```
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Importing base box 'laravel/homestead'...
==> default: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> default: Checking if box 'laravel/homestead' version '7.0.0' is up to date...
==> default: Setting the name of the VM: homestead_default_1549352737068_70025
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
    default:
    default: Vagrant insecure key detected. Vagrant will automatically replace
    default: this with a newly generated keypair for better security.
    default:
    default: Inserting generated public key within guest...
    default: Removing insecure key from the guest if it's present...
    default: Key inserted! Disconnecting and reconnecting using new SSH key...
==> default: Machine booted and ready!
```

Next problem that I see when ssh to it that it didn't have project folder with sub-folders that defined in Homestead.yaml file also it didn't have mysql connection also apache/nginx didn't belongs there(my web sites didn't wants to start). Here is my Homestead.yaml snippet:

```
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: ~/developing/projects
      to: /home/vagrant/projects

sites:
    - map: project_test.test
      to: /home/vagrant/projects/project_test/public
    - map: project_test2.test
      to: /home/vagrant/projects/project_test2/public

databases:
    - project_test
    - project_test2
```

I try multiple times `vagrant destroy && vagrant up --provision` but it didn't helps me. Can anybody help me what to do next?Any idea?

After uninstall all(Vagrant and Virtualbox) and install new version. It's partially works. I can ssh to it, it works mysql connect when set ip to be 127.0.0.1 (didn't bind to be "192.168.10.10" from Homestead file) but still can't access to any of my websites over my browser :(

Answer (score 0):

Try adding your sites to your local `/etc/hosts` file.

```
192.168.10.10   project_test.test
192.168.10.10   project_test2.test
```

Comment: Already have it but get error that server can't be found. Also try with 127.0.0.1 and get the same results.